# Django Many-to-Many Relation or One-to-Many relation

Tags: python, django

i have this tables in my django :

```
class User(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Photo(models.Model):
   publish_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   desc = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

User could publish Phtotos , and they can like Photos .but i don't know how to write the like in the phtoto , should i use one to many or many to many ?

and how could i get the Users that like a Photo .

thanks for help .

**UPDATE**

In the end I decided to use a many to many with a through model because I also wanted to record the time. The models I have settled on are these

```
class User(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=40)

 class Photo(Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)ss')
    publish_time =  models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes",through='PhotoLike',)

    def like(self, user):
        liked, created = PhotoLike.objects.get_or_create(photo=self,user=user)
        return liked

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'meinv'

class PhotoLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    like_time =  models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'meinv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to think about how photos are liked.

Can a user like many photos?

Can many photos be liked by the one user?

Then it is a many to many.

You would implement it like this

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    publish_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes")
```

Then, it works like this, you can add likes to a photo by

```
photoInstance.liked_by.add(user)
```

Access the likes of a photo this way

```
 photoInstance.liked_by.all()
```

To get all the photos a user liked

```
user.likes.all()
```

Comment: yes , a user can like many phtotos , and many photos can be liked by one user .

Comment: could i use through ? because i want add the like time to the like table .

Comment: Keep in mind using a through model does make things a little more complicated, for example you can't use the nice add() method.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: hi , i have rewrite my code  in the question , is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo  = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
```